# Laravel: Custom Auth with 2 tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-authentication

I am using Laravel 8, and I need to validate a user using data from 2 tables: users and customers. When user logs in, they will input 3 values: email, password and account. "Account" field comes from customer table.

So I need to do a join to access "account" field from "customers" table.

One option I see is:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials) {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        //Custom Query

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

In section "Custom Query", I can do a query to get customer data using $user->customer_id and check if matches $credentials['account'], but not sure if it is the best way.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up building a Custom Provider, and override "retrieveByCredentials" method, that made the trick.

```
public function retrieveByCredentials(array $credentials)
    {

        if (empty($credentials) ||
           (count($credentials) === 1 &&
            Str::contains($this->firstCredentialKey($credentials), 'password'))) {
            return;
        }

       
        $query = User::select(['customer.identifier', 'users.*'])->join('customer', 'customer_id', '=', 'customer.id');

        foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
            if (Str::contains($key, 'password')) {
                continue;
            }

            if($key == 'account') {
                $query->where('customer.identifier', '=', $credentials['account']);
            } else {
                $query->where($key, $value);
            }

        }

        return $query->first();

    }
```